# JLCPCB Preview shows up differently, is that how it is supposed to be?

Tags: pcb, eaglecad, pcb-fabrication

I am making a two sided PCB and was going to have it produced using JLCPCB. I made the PCB in Eagle, and this is my first time making it in Eagle (I am not new to PCB making, just the program). I exported the PCB using the default CAM settings. This is how eagle showed my PCB:
[image]

and this is how the JLCPCB Gerber View showed it:
[image]

It might be a little hard to see, but in the first picture you can see all of the traces, but in the JLCPCB preview only a portion of the traces show mostly on the left side. Is this on purpose, or is there some setting or something I am missing?

EDIT: I was thinking that it may have been rejected by JLCPCB for not passing their DRC, but I doubt that because I used the same set of design rules for the entire board, as well as used Eagle's built in DRC, which returned no errors or warnings.

Comment: The second image has much lower resolution than the first -- insufficient to show the very narrow clearances you've used. Try zooming in.

Comment: @DaveTweed Even after zooming in they do not show. Good idea though I was about to be very mad at myself lol

Comment: Assuming that the transistors are SOT-23, it appears that you are using 10-mil traces and something on the order of 2-3 mil clearance. Why so narrow, and are you sure that this board is manufacturable? From their [capabilities page](https://jlcpcb.com/capabilities/Capabilities): *"For Single&Double Layer PCB, the minimum spacing is 5 mil; For Multi Layer PCB, the minimum spacing is 3.5mil."*

Comment: Look at the Gerbers in a third party Gerber viewer : I use Gerbv from the open source Geda project. Look at each layer individually (separate files) as well as he overall view.

Comment: Really fine clearances like will reduce yield on the boards and can cause other issues.  JLCPCB is also pretty good about responding to questions, so you should just ask them whether there is an issue with the board.  I've had twenty or so 4 layer boards done by JLCPCB and not had any issues, and other than their site really sucking for finding appropriate parts their assembly service is hard to beat.

Comment: @DaveTweed I used 6mil traces, which is 1mil above the minimum (Which in hindsight is not a lot, but should be doable). And yes the transistors are SOT-23. Minimum clearance according the JCLPCB is 3.5mil

Comment: If those traces are 6 mil, then your clearances are a LOT less, about 1 mil. As I pointed out, they require 5 mil clearance on 2-layer boards.

Comment: @DaveTweed Do you mean clearances between the traces and pads? or between pads? or between traces?

Comment: @DaveTweed I changed the grid in eagle to 5mil, and looking at an area that did not have any traces showing, I manually checked and everything seemed to be at least two grid boxes away

Comment: @DaveTweed I reviewed my design rules and just realized I made the same mistake in the DRC that I made in the comments. I realized for two sided is 5mil, not 3.5mil. I redid the DRCa and lo and behold there are errors. I will fix them, thank you

Comment: The clearance rule applies to any two pieces of copper that are not supposed to be electrically connected to each other -- pads, vias, traces, pours, etc. And are you REALLY sure that 6-mil traces are enough for your 12V power connections?

Comment: @DaveTweed So I fixed all of the traces (Which was only about 10) that did not pass the DRC) and the initial image on the website definitely shows more traces (can't tell if it shows all because of the resolution), but when I go into the gerber viewer it barely shows any! I will most likely ask jlcpcb about the PCB if you do not have any more ideas

Comment: I'm really curious about the purpose of this board. I'm guessing that the large 4-pin components are optoisolators. Their inputs are connected in a row-column matrix (multiple modules are edge-stackable), and their outputs drive the transistors which in turn drive some kind of 2-pin through-hole device, probably LEDs. If this is essentially a 5x6 LED matrix display, this looks like a really expensive way to go about it.

Comment: @DaveTweed Yes this is a matrix, but not for LEDS. It is for coils of wire to make a coil matrix, as to have a positionable magnetic field. I have to say though I am very impressed as how you got all of that  right from just the pcb. I am aware that it does have a lot of components, but this was the best I was able to figure it out to fit the specs I need. Which is a matrix that can be controlled via 5V 40mA max and control coils that need 70mA of current. (The coils = 170ish Ohms). If you have any other ideas (Im happy to hear) before I order a pcbs and more parts let me know lol.

Comment: If you only intend to activate one coil at a time, then the individual drivers are really overkill. You should have a set of column drivers and a set of row drivers, and the matrix board itself should only have the coils and a series diode for each coil.

Comment: @DaveTweed Hi I just want to thank you for your help. I will definitely look into it and I appreciate the insight. When you say column drivers and row drivers Im assuming you mean one driver for each column and one driver for each row? I had thought of that earlier in the design process but what to use as the driver confused me, as just using transistors would not work as they would have to be high side and low side switches. I would love to discuss this more so I could get the best result, so if you want to talk about it my Discord is Jared Cohen#5265. Or we could keep it here as well.